# How do you code an R function so that it 'knows' to look in 'data' for the variables in other arguments?

Tags: r

If you run:

```
mod <- lm(mpg ~ factor(cyl), data=mtcars)
```

It runs, because lm knows to look in mtcars to find both mpg and cyl.

Yet `mean(mpg)` fails as it can't find mpg, so you do `mean(mtcars$mpg)`.

How do you code a function so that it knows to look in 'data' for the variables?

```
myfun <- function (a,b,data){
    return(a+b)
}
```

This will work with:

```
myfun(mtcars$mpg, mtcars$hp)
```

but will fail with:

```
myfun(mpg,hp, data=mtcars )
```

Cheers

Comment: I don't think I understand this enough to post a concise answer, but @Hadley has put together a quite thorough walk through explaining this here: https://github.com/hadley/devtools/wiki/Evaluation.

Comment: Cheers Chase, I knew Hadley would be one to ask, given ggplot sprung to mind as a set of functions that work this way. Will have a read now.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Here's how I would code `myfun()`:

```
myfun <- function(a, b, data) {
    eval(substitute(a + b), envir=data, enclos=parent.frame())
}

myfun(mpg, hp, mtcars)
#  [1] 131.0 131.0 115.8 131.4 193.7 123.1 259.3  86.4 117.8 142.2 140.8 196.4
# [13] 197.3 195.2 215.4 225.4 244.7  98.4  82.4  98.9 118.5 165.5 165.2 258.3
# [25] 194.2  93.3 117.0 143.4 279.8 194.7 350.0 130.4
```

If you're familiar with `with()`, it's interesting to see that it works in almost exactly the same way:

```
> with.default
# function (data, expr, ...) 
# eval(substitute(expr), data, enclos = parent.frame())
# <bytecode: 0x016c3914>
# <environment: namespace:base>
```

In both cases, the key idea is to first create an expression from the symbols passed in as arguments and then evaluate that expression using `data` as the 'environment' of the evaluation.

The first part (e.g. turning `a + b` into the expression `mpg + hp`) is possible thanks to `substitute()`. The second part is possible because `eval()` was beautifully designed, such that it can take a `data.frame` as its evaluation environment.

Answer (score 5):

`lm` "knows" to look in its `data` argument because it actually constructs a call to `model.frame` using its own call as the base. If you look at the code for `lm`, you'll see the necessary machinery in the first dozen lines or so.

You could replicate this for your own ends, but if your needs are simpler, you don't have to go to the same extent. For example:

```
myfun <- function(..., data)
eval(match.call(expand.dots=FALSE)$...[[1]], data)
```

Or, just look at `evalq`.

Answer (score 3):

This is not exactly like what you asked for, but if you don't know about `with()` this might be an option:

```
 myfun <- function (a,b){
    return(a+b)
 }
 with(mtcars, myfun(mpg, hp))
```

You can remove the `data` argument to myfun for this.

Comment: Cheers, I mean no offense with this obviously, but I'm more trying to make the function better (for user simplicity) than use a workaround.