# How can you add (say a vectors name) to an object of type 'formula' within a function?

Tags: class, r, formula

This is a very trimmed down version of what I want to do, I can't paste my exact problem cause the code is too long and complex but I think this gets at the root of issue. Thanks to Josh's answer to this question [How do you code an R function so that it 'knows' to look in 'data' for the variables in other arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8484664/how-do-you-code-an-r-function-so-that-it-knows-to-look-in-data-for-the-varia) I'm part way there.

```
example <- function(model, xvar3=NULL, xvar4=NULL, data){
    print(class(model))
    #xvar3 <- eval(substitute(xvar3), envir=data, enclos=parent.frame())
    #xvar4 <- eval(substitute(xvar4), envir=data, enclos=parent.frame())
    print(class(xvar3))
    xvar5 <- xvar4^2
    mod <- glm( model + xvar3 + xvar5, data=data)    
    return(mod)
}

example(mpg ~ cyl, hp, wt, data=mtcars)
```

This fails. If you remove the comments (based on help from previous question) it solves the problem of 'finding' hp and wt. 'model' is of class formula and I would like that to become 'mpg ~ cyl + xvar3 + xvar5' so that the glm will run. But I can't seem to be able to add them to the formula.

I've been toying around with 'call' classes and further with 'eval', and 'as.formula' with variations of 'paste' and 'noquote' etc but can't see to get it to stick.

Comment: You could just use `update` on a starting glm....

Comment: Thanks Hong, initial play with that suggests the same issue with getting the 'word' xvar3 printed in there (for lack of the correct term) rather than having the actual vector of data printed. That probably reads very poorly.

Comment: The point is that you want to add more terms to a model. That's what `update` is for. It just looks like you're reinventing the wheel, basically.

Comment: Feel free to put up an answer showing how update could work in this scenario, I couldn't get it to work for this particular setting.. I'd be reinventing the wheel if I was looking for a 'new' update command, I'm not. I'm looking for a way to run a model once with 'terms' added in the way described. In my actual problem this is inside a loop and there is more than just 2 variables added (this is just a simplified reproducible example here), so running a model once, then updating multiple times, within a loop running multiple times would be a very inefficient method for my actual problem.

Comment: @HongOoi - Good point about `update`. There is still some work to be done with the environment to make it work in this case though. See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way. The trick I used is to create a new formula based on the given one + the two extra variables. I then did a trick with the environment of the formula so that both `xvar3`/`xvar5` AND any variables local to the caller can be used.

`glm` will always look in the formula's environment AND in the data for variables (and nowhere else!). That's why the formula environment must the manipulated a bit in this case: it contains `xvar3` and `xvar5`, and the parent environment is set to the original formula's environment so that it is also searched for variables (`foo` in the last example)...

```
example <- function(model, xvar3=NULL, xvar4=NULL, data){
    e <- new.env(parent=environment(model))
    e$xvar3 <- eval(substitute(xvar3), envir=data, enclos=parent.frame())
    e$xvar4 <- eval(substitute(xvar4), envir=data, enclos=parent.frame())
    e$xvar5 <- e$xvar4^2

    model <- update(model, . ~ . + xvar3 + xvar5)
    environment(model) <- e

    mod <- glm(model, data=data)

    return(mod)
}

example(mpg ~ cyl, hp, wt, data=mtcars)

# Using a local variable should work too:
doit <- function(d) {
   foo <- d$cyl+1
   example(mpg ~ foo, hp, wt, data=d)
}
doit(mtcars)
```

Comment: Edited to use `update` instead of messing with the formula `call` object directly.

Comment: I think you're better off manipulating the formula, rather than moving the data around.

Comment: @hadley - Yes, if you can express the new data in the formula (like `wt^4` here)... But if you need to merge in other data you need something like this. An alternative is to add the new columns `xvar5` etc to the `data.frame`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I'd do it:

```
add_vars <- function(model, xvar3=NULL, xvar4=NULL, data){
  # Capture the unevalated calls to xvar3 and xvar4
  xvar3 <- substitute(xvar3)
  xvar4 <- substitute(xvar4)

  # Use substitute to create the correct formula to supply to update
  update_f <- eval(substitute(. ~ . + xvar3 + I(xvar4 ^ 2), 
    list(xvar3 = xvar3, xvar4 = xvar4)))

  # Modify the original formula string
  update(model, update_f)
}

add_vars(mpg ~ cyl, hp, wt)
# mpg ~ cyl + hp + I(wt^2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option for this (from a colleague):

```
example <- function(model, xvar3=NULL, xvar4=NULL, data){

    data$xvar3 <- eval(substitute(xvar3), envir=data, enclos=parent.frame())
    data$xvar4 <- eval(substitute(xvar4), envir=data, enclos=parent.frame())
    data$xvar5 <- data$xvar4^2

    model <- as.formula(paste(model[2], paste(model[3], "xvar4","xvar5", sep="+"), sep="~"))
    mod <- glm(model, data=data)
    return(mod)
}

example(mpg ~ cyl, hp, wt, data=mtcars)
```

I like this it's quite clean.