# Use data.frame in custom function?

Tags: r, function, dataframe

Often functions that work with `data.frames` have the ability to let the user provide a dataset, so that the user can use its columns in a straight forward way. E.g.:

```
lm(mpg~cyl+gear,data=mtcars)
```

Instead of using `mtcars$cyl` in the formula, we can simply use `cyl`.  How can I implement such behavior in custom built functions?

Comment: You can always look at the source of `lm` and see what's going on, or this wiki by Hadley may be of interest: https://github.com/hadley/devtools/wiki/Evaluation

Comment: very nice. thx Chase and James . Sometimes i just seem to forget about nice things...

Comment: Another good place to look for a worked example is the `subset.data.frame` function code.

Comment: Here was my answer to a recent ~ identical question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8484664/how-do-you-code-an-r-function-so-that-it-knows-to-look-in-data-for-the-varia/8484970#8484970

Comment: +1 on that other thread for you Josh, I think i am finally gettin started with other environments but global. Thx for the more elaborate answer though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several different techniques for this, described in [Standard nonstandard valuation rules](http://developer.r-project.org/nonstandard-eval.pdf).