# Writing functions which take data.frame column names as argument parameters

Tags: r, ggplot2

Some functions in `R` are able to take a `data.frame` as an argument, while having separate arguments whom can take the `names` of the `data.frame` (without having to quote them as strings).

A concrete example of this is the function `qplot` in the `ggplot2` package:

```
myDF <- data.frame(values=rnorm(5*2), group=c(rep("A", 5), rep("B", 5)))
qplot(values, data=myDF, colour=group, geom="density")
```

`qplot` is able to take `values` and `group` and know that they are columns of `myDF`.

Now if I want to write a wrapper function that does some preprocessing before plotting, I lose that functionality:

```
# A silly example. But lets assume our dataframe has more than 1 group column
silly.wrapper <- function(dataframe, colour) {
  dataframe$values <- dataframe$values*2
  qplot(values*2, data=dataframe, geom="density", colour=colour)
}
```

now if i try to call `silly.wrapper` and give it `colour=group` it throws an error that the object group hasn't been declared (as you would expect):

```
# We have to call print because its a lattice plot so returned qplot won't render
# otherwise. Removing call to print still results in the same error.
print(silly.wrapper(myDF, colour=group))
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'group' not found
In addition: Warning message:
In eval(expr, envir, enclos) : restarting interrupted promise evaluation
```

I've also tried using `...`:

```
silly.wrapper <- function(dataframe, ...) {
  dataframe$values <- dataframe$values*2
  qplot(values*2, data=dataframe, geom="density", ...)
}
```

But get the same error message.

This leads me to a more general question: How does one write a function, like `qplot`, that doesn't check for an object's existence until later, i.e. accessing it as a column of a dataframe?

Comment: Don't use qplot, use ggplot and aes_string instead.

Comment: Is that related to the answer? And if so can you elaborate? Otherwise it's not a particularly helpful comment.

Comment: Yes, @Jorans comment is very much related to the answer. Look at how `qplot` and `aes` work........

Comment: Re: your more general question, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8484664/how-do-you-code-an-r-function-so-that-it-knows-to-look-in-data-for-the-varia/8484970#8484970) this might be give you some insight into how a function can be constructed such that it searches for user-supplied names in a specified data.frame.

Comment: It was the best I could do in the amount of time I had on just me phone.

Comment: Have a look at http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Computing-on-the-language.html which describes the techniques that qplot uses, the problem that you encountered, and possible solutions.